# Is there a constant $\alpha$ such that: $P_{n+1} < P_n.\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^\alpha$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers

> > Is there a constant $\alpha$ such that:

$$P_{n+1} < P_n \cdot \left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^\alpha$$

Or

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln\frac{P_{n+1}}{P_n}}{\ln\frac{n+1}{n}} < +\infty$$

Where $P_n$ is $n$-th prime number.

In the table [The 80 known maximal prime gaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap#Numerical_results):

- $\alpha < 33.3$ with $P_n=1693182318746371$
- $\alpha < 35.77$ with $P_n=18361375334787046697$

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As $P_n$ is asymptotically $n\log n$, your question is equivalent to the following. Is it true that
$$P_{n+1}-P_n\ll\log n?$$
In other words, is it true that the actual gap between primes is always at most a constant times the average (expected) gap? The answer is "no" by a 1931 result of Westzynthius. For the best known lower bound (for infinitely many prime gaps) see the paper of [Ford-Green-Konyagin-Maynard-Tao](https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.5029).

Comment: Thanks you very much